# Android SDK "Slide" Capability

Tags: android, android-animation

Does the Droid SDK support sliding your finger across the screen to go back to the previous screen, instead of using the back key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean "slide" as the unlocking system of i-phone.

Nothing is inbuilt for going back to previous screen..for implementing finger detection Implement  [GESTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/package-summary.html)  and implement OnFling()  function.

OnFling() is the function that fired when the same kind of action performed as event unlocking the i-phone.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Once you pointed me in the right direction, this link had a good example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in for that. You are welcome to watch for that gesture and call `finish()` on your activity, if you want. However, that is unusual and may cause confusion for your users.